How to get host IP from inside Docker container when using network_mode host?
I am using network_mode: host with docker compose. I am trying to get the IP of my machine in its local network from inside the docker container, and I'm not sure how to do this.
On my local machine, there is an ens7 network interface, but even when using network_mode: host, that interface is not present.
Similarly, ip route | grep default | awk '{print $3}' in the container gives an IP that starts with 127, instead of the actual IP of my machine on its local network.
Output of ip a:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: tap0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65520 qdisc fq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e6:e5:f1:a8:60:26 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.100/24 scope global tap0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::e4e5:f1ff:fea8:6026/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:41:4a:e8:b0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:41ff:fe4a:e8b0/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


Are you running under Linux? Can you update your question to include the complete output of ip addr and ip route from inside the container? A default route starting with 127 shouldn't work, ever, in any situation.

@larsks Added output of ip addr, maybe the issue is that I'm using rootless docker.

If you've disabled Docker's networking layer with network_mode: host (not typically encouraged) then the container should be able to directly see the host's network interfaces.  Determining "the IP of the machine" then becomes the same problem you have without Docker, including that it's very normal for a machine to have multiple physical and virtual network interfaces like you see here.

I think your default route starts with 172, not 127. It looks like you can't use network_mode: host with rootless Docker. Try running it as root instead and it will probably work as expected. If you really want to solve your problem using rootless Docker, please update your question to describe the problem you're trying to solve. Why do you need the ip of your machine?
